# Why isn't my Kivy window working even though the code is correct?

Tags: python, camera, kivy

I'm a Kivy beginner. I made a selfie app, it has no errors or syntax problems and (in theory) should work. Whenever I run it, it creates the window but doesn't actually load anything! It's just a blank black screen

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

ind = 0


class applic(App):
    def make_screen(self):
        self.camera = Camera
        self.camera.resolution = (810, 810)
        butt = Button(text="CLICK ME!")
        butt.size_hint = (.6, .3)
        butt.pos_hint = {'x': .25, 'y': .25}
        butt.bind(on_press=self.save_selfie())
        screen = BoxLayout()
        screen.add_widget(self.camera)
        screen.add_widget(butt)
        return screen

    def save_selfie(self, *args):
        global ind
        ind += 1
        print("success")
        self.camera().export_to_png(f"picture{ind}.png")

if __name__=='__main__':
    applic().run()
```

what it returns:

```
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system

[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.4.0 - Build 20.19.15.5058'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 4

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.40 - Build 20.19.15.5058'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>

[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider

[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not 
docked

[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

Comment: im using python (windows 10), no errors. installed with the pycharm packages thing

Comment: this has been seen 20 times with no comments or answers... guys please help me

Comment: Since you have no `.kv` file, return method `make_screen` from the method `build`. Also you haven't created any camera instance, change `Camera` to `Camera()`(note the `()`). There are few more things to fix.

Comment: @ApuCoder can you make an answer with all of the problems fixed?

Answer (score 0):

you forget the build function

you must return the screen in the build function

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

ind = 0


class applic(App):
    def make_screen(self):
        self.camera = Camera
        self.camera.resolution = (810, 810)
        butt = Button(text="CLICK ME!")
        butt.size_hint = (.6, .3)
        butt.pos_hint = {'x': .25, 'y': .25}
        butt.bind(on_press=self.save_selfie)
        screen = BoxLayout()
        screen.add_widget(self.camera)
        screen.add_widget(butt)
        return screen

    def save_selfie(self, *args):
        global ind
        ind += 1
        print("success",f"picture{ind}.png")
        self.camera().export_to_png(f"picture{ind}.png")
    def build(self):
        return self.make_screen()


if __name__=='__main__':
    applic().run()
```

Comment: It's still just a black screen @programming lab

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of your posted code that should work (worked in my case). I've modified it line by line so that you can follow the necessary changes that have been made.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

ind = 0


class applic(App):
#    def make_screen(self):
    def build(self):
    # Here everything has been defined in the method build.
    # You can follow the other way as mentioned in the comment.
#        self.camera = Camera
        self.camera = Camera()
#        self.camera.resolution = (810, 810)
        # Not sure setting resolution will work or not !
        butt = Button(text="CLICK ME!")
        butt.size_hint = (.6, .3)
        butt.pos_hint = {'x': .25, 'y': .25}
#        butt.bind(on_press=self.save_selfie())
        butt.bind(on_press=self.save_selfie)
        screen = BoxLayout()
        screen.add_widget(self.camera)
        screen.add_widget(butt)
        return screen

    def save_selfie(self, *args):
        global ind
        ind += 1
        print("success")
#        self.camera().export_to_png(f"picture{ind}.png")
        self.camera.export_to_png(f"picture{ind}.png") # Provided the path is correct.

if __name__=='__main__':
    applic().run()
```

Comment: its giving me an error:`TypeError:  'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: As I said, I found the code in the answer working as expected. However here are some suggestions: 1. Make sure you ran exactly the same code, 2. In case there are still some issues, change `Camera` with some other widget like `Button` etc. 3. Still having issues, check log, try reinstalling.